# Why is the server getting an empty object when calling Meteor.method with a non-empty object?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I call a Meteor method with a object as an argument, if this is at all possible?

Here is what I'm struggling with if it helps

I have the method:

```
'user.some.update.position'(coords) {
    console.log('method: ', 'user.some.update.position');
    console.log('this.userid: ', this.userId);
    console.log('coords: ', coords);

    check(coords, Object);
    check(coords.latitude, Number);
    check(coords.longitude, Number);
    check(coords.accuracy, Number);

    if (!this.userId)
      throw new Meteor.Error('Not logged in', 'You are not logged in, please log in');

    Meteor.users.update({
      _id: this.userId
    }, {
      $set: {
        coords,
        lastUpdated: new Date()
      }
    });
    return coords;
  }
```

Which I want to call from the client like this:

```
> var coords = Geolocation.currentLocation().coords
undefined
> coords
Coordinates {latitude: 58.2441766, longitude: 8.376727899999999, altitude: null, accuracy: 25, altitudeAccuracy: null…}
> Meteor.call('user.some.update.position', coords, function(err, res) {if(err) console.log('err: ', err); if(res) console.log('res: ', res);})
undefined
VM7572:2 err:  errorClass {error: 400, reason: "Match failed", details: undefined, message: "Match failed [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
```

But when I do that the server complains that `coords` is a empty object like this:

```
method:  user.some.update.position
I20160220-15:49:34.226(1)? this.userid:  nHqj3zaSWExRmqBZq
I20160220-15:49:34.226(1)? currentLocation:  {}
I20160220-15:49:34.227(1)? Exception while invoking method 'user.some.update.position' Error: Match error: Expected number, got undefined
I20160220-15:49:34.227(1)?     at Object.check (packages/check/match.js:33:1)
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at [object Object]._meteorMeteor.Meteor.methods.user.some.update.position (server/methods/drivers.js:36:5)
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at packages/check/match.js:103:1
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at Object.Match._failIfArgumentsAreNotAllChecked (packages/check/match.js:102:1)
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1695:18)
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:708:19
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160220-15:49:34.228(1)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:706:40
I20160220-15:49:34.229(1)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20160220-15:49:34.229(1)? Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
```

And the client complains:

```
err:  errorClass {error: 400, reason: "Match failed", details: undefined, message: "Match failed [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}
```

Edit: I am using ES6 and object destructuring.

Comment: Have you tried Christian's first suggestion (explicitly send only lat, lon and accuracy)? You can also try to log the data you receive and view what is being sent via the websocket using the dev tools (or the DDP inspector utility).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object that you are getting from the geolocation request implements the [Coordinates](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/#coordinates_interface) interface. You cannot assume anything else about it.

In your case, the object is likely not serializable via EJSON, and therefore cannot be used as a Meteor method call argument as it is.

The method call routine calls `EJSON.clone()` and given the `Coordinates` object, it returns an empty object.

```
> EJSON.clone(coordinates)
Object {}
```

In Chrome's implementation, I assume that the properties are "owned" deeper in the prototype chain. EJSON relies on underscore's `_.keys` function when cloning, which in turn lists the object's own properties.

```
> coordinates.hasOwnProperty("latitude")
false
> "latitude" in coordinates
true
```

Since [creating a custom EJSON](https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-create-a-custom-ejson-type) type for it seems unrealistic, you can do as @ChristianFritz suggested or use underscore's `_.pick`.

```
> _.pick(coordinates, ['latitude', 'longitude', 'accuracy'])
Object {latitude: 12.1212, longitude: 34.3434, accuracy: 50}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I fixed the problem by cloning the object manually. Yoy were the first to actually answer my question instead of nitpicking on other parts of the code

Comment: You are welcome. I would not call it nitpicking, as they do raise valid points (which are still valid) and the issue is hidden pretty deeply. I would suggest you set the coordinates in your method more explicitly (by picking only the validated keys from the object received by the server), as it may hold unwanted keys.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear from your error message that your object has nothing in it. please look at the 4th line of your error message, `currentLocation` contains no property. Sending a valid object will solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated op with new client side code, which clearly reflects that I am passing a coordinates object to Meteor.call('user.some.update.position') , I can't seem to figure out why it should be empty when the method is executing on the server.

Answer (score 1):

what is `$set: {  coords,` supposed to do? you can't do that. You need to take the content of that object apart and put it back together into the `$set`. Assuming that `coords = {lat: 1234, lng: 2345}` (or similar), you would do:

```
$set: {
  lat: coords.lat,
  lng: coords.lng,
  ...
```

or you can just add it as a sub-object;

```
$set: {
  coords: coords,
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: I don't get it. This is not an instance where you are destructing anything. There is no assignment (`=`) in this.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of object-shorthand, so if I am correct {coords} should be the same as {coords: coords}.

Answer (score 1):

Both the answers by Christian and Faysal contain valid information, I just want to expand on them a little:

The actual exception you're seeing, `Error: Match error: Expected number, got undefined`, is happening because of this line of code:

`check(coords.latitude, Number);`.

In your console log, you can see that coords is just an empty object:

`I20160220-15:49:34.226(1)? currentLocation:  {}`

So when your check() method checks the currentLocation for coords.latitude, it throws the exception because coords.latitude is of type undefined, not of type Number like you said it would be in the check() statement.

Once you fix that, Christian pointed out that you'll get another error because of your update statement.  [MongoDB's $set](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) requires you to pass in an object with the schema `{ $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }`.  You are passing in: `{ $set: {}, lastUpdated: <A valid Date> }`.  Because that empty object doesn't match the `field: value` schema $set is expecting, it'll throw an exception.  As he says, you'll need to either parse out that object into individual properties or pass it to a property itself.

Comment: Ok so i get what you guys are trying to say, but i think you might be misinterpreting my code, to put it simpler, if i do: ```var coords = Geolocation.currentLocation().coords;
console.log(coords);
VM6643:2 Coordinates {}
undefined
Meteor.call('user.some.update.position', coords, function(err, res) {if(err) console.log('err: ', err); if(res) console.log('res: ', res);})
undefined
VM6644:2 err:  errorClass {error: 400, reason: "Match failed", details: undefined, message: "Match failed [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}``` that may explain what i am doing simpler, still getting the same result

Comment: If it is ok that coords are null, change 

   `check(coords.latitude, Number);
    check(coords.longitude, Number);
    check(coords.accuracy, Number);`

To:
`check(coords.latitude, Match.Optional(Number));
    check(coords.longitude, Match.Optional(Number));
    check(coords.accuracy, Match.Optional(Number));`

Comment: No, it's not ok for coords to be null, I'm sorry if my question was unclear but what I need help for is finding out why coords is an empty object on the server, when i clearly pass in a coordinates object to Meteor.call() on the client, i have updated my client side code in my op to reflect this better.

Comment: I think what all of the answerers are confused on is that it looks like your coordinates are coming back as empty on both the client and the server.

Comment: I'm just going to try and convince you another time that the coords object is not empty on the client, but only on the server: ```var coords2 = {accuracy: 25, latitde: 58.24, longitude: 8.37}
undefined
Meteor.call('user.some.update.position', coords2, function(err, res) {if(err) console.log('err: ', err); if(res) console.log('res: ', res);})
undefined
VM7797:2 err:  errorClass {error: 400, reason: "Match failed", details: undefined, message: "Match failed [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}``` And im still getting the same response at the server.

Comment: You have a typo: `latitde` instead of `latitude`.