# Meteor method not running on server

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following code,

```
Meteor.methods({
  markPaid: function(expense) {
    check(this.userId, String);
    check(expense.id, String);

    Expenses.update({'_id': expense.id}, {$set: {paid: true}}, function(error) {
      return error;
    });
  }
});
```

called by

```
Meteor.call('markPaid', expense, function(error, result) {
  //handle error if any.
});
```

When I call this from my client the code executes client side, as is expected with meteor's so-called optimistic UI, but the method does not run server side. My actual database never updates.

Thank you!

Comment: If your method being called at all? Maybe the db function is wrong and errors out? Try logging stuff

Comment: I removed my console.log functions for brevity. Logs get called in the client, but not on the server. The DB function worked just find before I removed insecure and moved the db actions to methods.

Comment: The expense object has a start property that is a moment object. Something is going wrong passing that expense object to the server. An exception is thrown, and causes the server side method to not run. I've worked around by just passing the object id rather than the whole object, but I don't understand at all why it's failing; TypeError: config._d.getTime is not a function. (In 'config._d.getTime()', 'config._d.getTime' is undefined)
2

Comment: @AlexLauni You should be storing dates as timestamps, not `moment` objects - that would definitely make things messy.

Answer (score 2):

according the Meteor docs on Meteor.call (c.f. https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call)

> Meteor.call(name, [arg1, arg2...], [asyncCallback])
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> arg1, arg2... EJSON-able Object
>   Optional method arguments

the arguments must be JSON. a moment object is not JSON. that's why passing an id, as you did, works, but your full JS object does not.

Comment: I would say that it is not EJSON-serializable (as EJSON is a superset of JSON). See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35535283/268093) that describes this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Is the method being called inside observechanges?
I had a similar issue:

```
let a = MyCollection.find({something:'something'}); 
a.observeChanges ({
    changed( id, fields) {
        console.log('Im here');
        Meteor.call ('awesomeMethod', 
            'param',
             (error, ans) => {
                 handel error; return; }                                    
                 console.log(ans);
             }
         );                
    }
});
```

And the same things were happening; only the simulation was running, but calling the method from the console worked well, so I decided to change the Meteor call to another place.